# JDBCResourceDAO Failed to delete the resource with id - WSO2 API Manager

Tags: java, mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 1.8 with MySQL. I'm getting below error for no reason.

```
ERROR - JDBCResourceDAO Failed to delete the resource with id 758. Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to 
binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row
-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses
 a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UN
COMMITTED.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error occur due to replication on Mysql DB with the WSO2 product.

According to [ERROR 1598 (HY000): Binary Logging not Possible. Message: Transaction Level READ-COMMITTED in InnoDB is not Safe for Binlog Mode STATEMENT](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/troubleshooting-guide/mysql/import/binlog_mode_statement):

> There are several solutions for the issue:
>
> - You need to change the binlog mode to either **ROW** or **MIXED** in order to run the load of the data into the database
>
>   ```
>   mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
>   ```
> - If you are not planning to use your MySQL server for the replication consider turning the binary logging off by removing the
>     option `--log-bin` from the command options for the mysqld utility
>     starting the MySQL server.